# Nothing displaying in view port shading

Tags: objects, collections

Im currently new to blender so do forgive me if i dont get explain the correct terms.

Im following a simple tutorial online and im ive created a few objects (List in the top right corner) ive organised them into collections.

Now for some reason, all the objects i have created are disappeared. They only appear in render mode. Can someone please help me what ive done wrong?

Thanks

[image: ender]

Comment: Try pressing Shift+C to show reframe the viewport and show all items, also check that you aren't in local vide mode by pressing / on the numpad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just accidentally switched to Local view.

To get out go *View > Local View > Toggle Local View*
Shortcut: <kbd>Numpad /</kbd>

[image]

[Blender Manual on Local View](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/views.html#contextual-views)

> Local view isolates selected objects, so that they are the only ones visible in the viewport. This is useful for working on objects that are obscured by other ones, or to speed up the viewport performance in heavy scenes.

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked!